# js function call returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm currently struggling with the following issue:

I have a function call like this:

```
foo = this.initializeFoo(id, array); // console.log() says: undefined
```

And the function:

```
export function initializeFoo(id, array) {
    axios.get(API_URL + '/route/' + id)
        .then(response => {
            let copyPayload = [...response.data.foo];
            let copyArray = [...array];

        // Some operations  
            copyArray = copyArray.filter(x => {
                let exists = false;
                copyPayload.forEach(payload => {
                    if (x.id === payload.id) {
                        x["newAttribute"] = id;
                        exists = true;
                    }
                });
                return exists
            });

            console.log("Returning copyArray", copyArray); // Displays the proper data
            return copyArray;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({loaded: false});
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

The question is: Why is the `console.log()` `undefined`? I guess it has something to do with the way I `return` the array within the `axios` call, but I can't think of another way to do it.

I also don't want to use `setState` within the function, since I call a few initialize functions and I'd rather want to use one `setState` after I got all the data initialized.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Can I do it this way:

```
foo["blub"]  = this.initializeFoo(id, array).then(result => {
             return result;
        });
```

Comment: Didn't you actually forget to return the axios call? `return axios.get ... `?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: if you could use async/await, make the export function `async`, and await the response when assigning foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return from the `initializeFoo` method but that would return a `Promise` of the data and not the data itself.

To get the data:

```
this.initializeFoo(..args).then(copyArray => /* do something with the array */)
```

#### Update:

A `Promise` is a neat way to handle asynchronous activity. When you attach the `then` to a `Promise`, you're essentially saying "As soon as this promise resolves ***THEN*** execute the following block"

```
let result = this.initializeFoo(..args).then(copyArray => copyArray)
// if you were to inspect `result` here, it would also be a `Promise`!
```

If you still do not use `.then`, you could make your function `async`. This will allow you to use `await` in your function and you could essentially write code as if it were synchronous.

```
async function initializeFoo(id, array) {
    let response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/route/${id}`);
    // some operations on response
    let copyArray = this.massageResponse(response, array);

    // don't catch any exceptions here, let it bubble out...
    return copyData;
}
```

Now, since you didnt want to `setState` within the method, you'll have to do it from the place you called it.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // time to initialize data for this component
    this.initializeComponentData();
  }

  async function initializeComponentData() {
    // this function is called from `componentDidMount`
    try {
      let promiseOfBar = this.initializeFoo(id, array);

      // call another initializer 
      // - (this would have to be an async function as well)
      let promiseOfBaz = this.anotherInitalizer(id, array);  

      let foo = {};
      let response = await Promise.all(promiseOfBar, promiseOfBaz);
      foo['bar'] = response[0];
      foo['baz'] = response[1];

      // finally call `setState`
      this.setState({ ...foo, loaded: true });
    } catch (exception) {
      // catch any possible exceptions and `setState` accordingly
      this.setState({ loaded: false });
    }
  }

  // rest of the component 

  render() {
    // render logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updatet my initial question. Can you maybe have a look? Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks. Is there another way to return the data out of the promise then block?

Comment: You can change global variables or do `this.foo['bar'] = copyData` from within the `then` block but I wouldn't recommend that since you want to control what you do when. What I mean by that is that 1. you make call to a service to retrieve data 2. On retrieving the data you want to store that data into your component's state 3. On state change you want to render your component in a particular way. Now if you set a global variable, you wouldn't be able to keep track of when that global variable changes/changed.

Comment: when I do this within the  `then` block its not accessable outside `undefined`

Comment: its not a global var, just in scope of a function. And setstate is called later.

Comment: It wouldn't be accessible outside immediately because you're dealing with asynchronous activity. When you do `axios.get` it does not return the data immediately but instead returns a `Promise` of the data; the request goes over the network, fetches the resource and brings it back to your browser. When the browser has the data, it will then resolve the `Promise` that it returned to you with the data that it just fetched. _**THEN**_ you can decide what you want to do with that data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `return` the `axios.get(API_URL + '/route/' + id)` call as the follows

```
export function initializeFoo(id, array) {
    return axios.get(API_URL + '/route/' + id) // add return here
        .then(response => {
            let copyPayload = [...response.data.foo];
            let copyArray = [...array];

        // Some operations  
            copyArray = copyArray.filter(x => {
                let exists = false;
                copyPayload.forEach(payload => {
                    if (x.id === payload.id) {
                        x["newAttribute"] = id;
                        exists = true;
                    }
                });
                return exists
            });

            console.log("Returning copyArray", copyArray); // Displays the proper data
            return copyArray;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({loaded: false});
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

However, the function will now return a promise. You will have to do Something like:

```
return this.initializeFoo(id, array).then(result => {
    foo = result;
    console.log(foo)
}); // console.log() says: undefined
```

Or you can use `async/await`

Comment: His `foo` would now be a promise though, I think he is rather looking how to assign the array to foo

Comment: Ah, missed that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I've updatet my initial question. Can you maybe have a look? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do that, `result` wont be available outside the then block